# JOIN on Access "Lookup" field returns no results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a strange problem that I believe is related to the way my lookups are structured.

```
TABLE Category
   ID
   CategoryName

TABLE Product
   ID
   ProductName
   Category - Number (SELECT [Category].[ID], [Category].[Category Type] FROM Category ORDER BY [Category Type];)

TABLE SalePrices
   Several fields related to sale date, price, &c.
   ProductName - Text (SELECT [Product].[ID], [Product].[Product Name] FROM Product ORDER BY [Product Name];
```

For some reason I get a blank result set when I run the following query:

```
SELECT SalePrices.[Product Name], Product.[Product Name]
FROM SalePrices INNER JOIN Product ON SalePrices.[Product Name] = Product.[Product Name];
```

I have a query that displays the MIN of `SalePrices.UnitPrice` which I want to display with the `ProductName` and `CategoryName`, but I'm not getting results for that so I wanted to simplify things first.

When I join Product and Category I have to match `Product.[Category Type] = Category.ID;`, but when I try to do `SalePrices.[Product Name] = Product.[ID];` I get a `TYPE MISMATCH` error. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

The eventual goal is to combine the `SalesPrices` <-> `ProductName` join with this one:

```
SELECT Product.[Product Name], Category.[Category Type]
FROM Product INNER JOIN Category ON Product.[Category Type] = Category.ID;
```

Comment: One of the things that has me scratching my head is why the Product.Category lookup bound to the ID, but the SalePrices.ProductName lookup bound to the actual name.

Comment: " when I try to do SalePrices.[Product Name] = Product.[ID]; I get a TYPE MISMATCH "   Why would a product name, type text ever be equal to a product ID?

Comment: I was comparing that to the lookup for Product.Category. I'm not sure why one was Number and the other Text or how to change it without breaking the linked tables. What part of the lookup is determining whether the ID or TYPE/NAME field gets used?

Comment: I feel like you might not be familiar with joins (don't take offense, maybe I'm just really not understanding your problem), so can you say in just plain english what results you want your query(s) to return? I feel like I'm confusing myself.

Comment: MIN of SalePrice.UnitPrice (which I didn't go into here), SalePrice.ProductName, and Product.Category.

Comment: Did you try `SELECT Min(s.unitprice), s.productName, p.category FROM SalesPrice s INNER JOIN Product p ON s.productID = p.productID INNER JOIN Category ON p.productID = category.ID GROUP BY s.productname, p.category`

Comment: I don't even get that far: 

    `SELECT SalePrices.[Unit Price], SalePrices.[Product Name], Product.[Category Type]
    FROM SalePrices INNER JOIN Product ON SalePrices.[Product Name] = Product.[Product Name];`

I get no results.

Comment: Look at your data. Do you have any SalesPrice Product Names that are the same as Product Product Names?

Comment: Yes, they're lookups so it's basically linked. Here's the Access file: http://sevaits.com/stack/

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense now (that it doesn't make sense). It has something to do with Lookups, which I have NO idea about. It just seems ridiculous to me that you can't join on fields with lookups like that. By taking the lookups off and just leaving the values, the joins work fine. Reading up on lookup fields, it pretty much goes against everything that a RDBMS should do. I would do away with lookup fields, to be honest. It seems to overcomplicate your schema and make it only relevent in MS Access

Comment: Change the primary key of your `Category` table from `Category Type` to `ID`.  The relationship between `Category.[Category Type]` (text) and `Product.[Category Type]` (long integer) is wrong.  You should be joining on `Category.ID` instead.  Consider also enforcing referential integrity.

Comment: Lookup fields are evil: http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by @Scotch and @HansUp, defining "Lookup" fields in an Access table is generally regarded as a *Bad Idea* for all but the most trivial of cases. They hide what is really going in the database and they can lead to all kinds of confusion (as you have discovered) when you actually try to *use* them. (Ref: [here](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm), via comment by @HansUp.)

Your best course of action would be to replace the Lookup fields in your tables with regular numeric fields containing the ID (key) values in the related tables. Then, if necessary, you can create and save Select Queries to explicitly do the lookups and display the results as they previously appeared in the `[Product]` and `[SalePrices]` Datasheet Views.